# New module inside a module in javascript

Tags: javascript

Here is my module:

```
MyModule = (function () {

    var myModule = function MyModule(strInput) {
        if (false === (this instanceof MyModule)) {
            return new MyModule();
        }

        str = strInput;
    }

    var str;
    myModule.prototype.getStr = function () {
        return str;
    }

    myModule.prototype.test = function () {
        var testModule = new MyModule("testInside");
        console.log(testModule.getStr());
        console.log(str);
    }

    return myModule;
}());
```

Here is how I test my module:

```
document.getElementById("Button").onclick = function () {    
        var module = new MyModule("input");    
        module.test();    
    }
```

This code returns:

```
testInside   
testInside
```

to the console.log, but what I expect is:

```
testInside    
input
```

like I do in c# or java when I build a new class inside the same class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep the `str` private, you can make it like this:

```
MyModule = (function () {

    var myModule = function MyModule(strInput) {
        if (false === (this instanceof MyModule)) {
            return new MyModule();
        }

        var str = strInput;

        this.getStr = function () {
            return str;
        };

        this.test = function () {
            var testModule = new MyModule("testInside");
            console.log(testModule.getStr());
            console.log(str);
        };
    };

    return myModule;
}());
```

In this way the `str` is in the inner closure, so it's like an instance/object variable in other languages. If you put it in the outer closure it will act like a static/class variable. In both cases, the methods of the myModule object still can access it, but it's not visible from the outside.

Comment: OK, you learn me something but I will have a new question because if I return the new module and test outside, I get the same problem.

Comment: Strange, if I change test function to return the testModule and then call it like: 

    var m1 = new MyModule('m1');
    var m2 = m1.test();
    m1.getStr(); // returns "m1"
    m2.getStr(); // returns 'testInside'

This is what I would expect. Maybe there is some other problem?

Answer (score 0):

`str` is a variable stored inside the closure that returns `MyModule`. It is not a property of any object and it is shared between all instances of `MyModule`.

When you call `.test()`, you overwrite it.

If you want it to be associated with the object, then put it on the object:

```
//...
var myModule = function MyModule(strInput) {
    // ...
    this.str = strInput;
}
//...
myModule.prototype.getStr = function () {
    return this.str;
//...
    console.log(testModule.getStr());
    console.log(this.str);
//...
```

Comment: Ok, that's working. Thank you. So if I understand, I can share a var between all identical modules created and if one module change the var, all modules will be updated to reflect the change ?

Comment: But that is slightly different, because now the `str` is visible from outside and the client of the module can change it, so you lose the encapsulation.

Comment: Yes, you are right Georgi. Is it possible to keep str private as I do in c# or java ?

Comment: @Alphapage yes, look at my answer for an example of this